# HTML5 Boilerplate drawbacks

Tags: html, html5boilerplate

I've been using XHTML for about 3 years now, and didn't care much about HTML5 and CSS3 arrival. Several months ago I've stumbled upon [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and I'm starting to get very interested in it right now.

The only thing I can't find yet is drawbacks of using this set of best practices. I know, that the main goal of it to make site look the same on wide variety of browsers, but is there something I should be aware about?

Comment: You might want to be more specific about what you're after here. It's a little strange and vague to be asking about the drawbacks of best practices.

Comment: Just needed [docs](http://h5bp.com/docs/) really. My mistake for not finding it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there something I should be aware about?

Yes, definitely. **It's not a plug-and-play thing.** Or at least, it could be like that but it hasn't been conceived for that. And if you use it this way you can't enjoy its best. Boilerplate is very flexible and you have to learn how to customize it. Full stop.

My personal suggestion is to start experimenting with it and study the features it has to offer. Luckily for us it's well documented and you can learn *a lot*. Not only the boilerplate itself, but also the rules and best practices about HTML5, CSS3, resources loading and related issues/workarounds on performances, browsers quirks and how to fix them, tricks for mobile development, polyfills and conditional loading and a lot of other crazy stuffs. Once you are aware of its possibilities, if you'll find drawbacks you'll be able to customize the base boilerplate.

Start from [here](http://html5boilerplate.com/), read [the docs](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v8.0.0/dist/doc/TOC.md), follow every link and don't be tempted to take shortcuts. It takes time, but you'll be rewarder very well. If you have troubles ask.

For something more concrete, a drawback I found very quickly (but someone consider this a plus) is that the boilerplate doesn't provide a CSS grid. Not a huge problem, I discovered that [adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs/) is easily integrable, so I replaced normalize.css with adapt.js's reset stylesheet and used the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I noticed couple months back is the way javascript gets loaded at the bottom of the body. I'm not a big fan of this if not only it looks dirty. Also I tested the loading myself and didn't notice any better loading of javascript. In fact it ran a couple ms slower on a huge script.

Also the normalize.css I tried couple of times but found myself restyling more paddings and margins than before. Which is normal ofcourse since it's goal is somewhat similar but a different approach. I changed this to Eric Meyer's reset.css just because I'm used to it.

I really like the modernizr script and the way to implement things for x-browser results.
Google Analytics implementation for example.

Another small thing I remember was the placing of the title tag. I changed it to the top position for SEO reasons.